# filter array by index condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to filter array by indices condition. There is a functionality in `numpy` like following:

`np.where_index(lambda indices: indices[0]**2 + indices[1]**2 < 10, a)`?

(similar to filtering by value `np.where(a > 2, a)`)

Comment: what is shape of your array? and what is shape of result you expect

Answer (score 0):

you can use masking to do that like below

```py
arr = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
display(arr)
ind_x = np.arange(arr.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1)
ind_y = np.arange(arr.shape[1])

ind = (ind_x**2 + ind_y**2)<10

arr[ind]
```